# Directive Param Attributes in Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I understand that directive param attributes have been deprecated in Vue.js 2.0. So I can no longer do something such as `v-model="msg" number` inside of an `input` tag. How can get the same results without using the now deprecated param attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modifiers:

```php
<input v-model.number="msg">
```

Comment: Thanks. I never would've thought to do that. Is it anywhere in the docs, by chance?

Comment: 2.0 docs are not ready, but it's explained in the same github issue that the deprecation is documented in: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873